# Securing and encrypting ActiveMQ messages with .NET API

Tags: c#, ssl, activemq-classic

I'm creating a C# program which is sending messages with `ActiveMQ` like this:

```
IConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory("activemq:tcp://localhost:61616");
connection = (Connection)factory.CreateConnection();
connection.Start();
session = connection.CreateSession();
producer = session.CreateProducer(new ActiveMQTopic("topic1"));
ITextMessage msg = producer.CreateTextMessage();
msg.Text = Body;
producer.Send(msg);
```

How can I send the messages in a secure way using TLS/SSL with port 443? What do I need to do in the client side (also .NET) in order to receive it? Is there also a way to configure the clients to only receive such secured messages, and reject regular messages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActiveMQ Exception when trying to work with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58201771/activemq-exception-when-trying-to-work-with-ssl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to mention all the relevant information in one place
For the **one way TLS** there is almost no client side configuration required, just update connection string  `activemq:ssl://broker.host:61617`. The certification burden is on a server.

#### To configure your local ActiveMQ broker

First generate self-signed key in server.ts keystore file

```
<JAVA_HOME>\bin\keytool -genkey -alias broker -keyalg RSA -keystore <AMQ_HOME>\conf\server.ks
```

Then edit the config file ([AMQ  Install Dir]\conf\activemq.xml)
define ssl context

```xml
<broker ...>
...
  <sslContext> 
    <sslContext keyStore="file:${activemq.conf}/server.ks"
              keyStorePassword="password" /> 
  </sslContext>
```

configure ssl transport

```xml
<transportConnectors>
    <transportConnector name="ssl" uri="ssl://localhost:61617" />
</transportConnectors>
```

Finally start/restart ActiveMQ broker

Now you can make a connection using this connection string:
`activemq:ssl://localhost:61617?transport.acceptInvalidBrokerCert=true`

At this point you should have a working prototype! and should start working on real certificates.

#### Using self-signed certificate

If you fine with self-signed certificates you can export one from the broker's key store, copy it to a client's bin and mention it in a connection string.

export:
`<JAVA_HOME>\bin\keytool -export -alias broker -keystore <AMQ_HOME>\conf\server.ks -file broker_cert`

connection string:
`activemq:ssl://localhost:61617?transport.BrokerCertFilename=broker_cert`

#### Two-way TLS

***to be continued ...***

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure SSL on the [broker](http://activemq.apache.org/ssl-transport-reference) and then use a properly configured client connection using the SSL transport to connect to the broker.  The is an old article [here](http://timbish.blogspot.com/2010/04/ussing-ssl-in-nmsactivemq.html) on the .NET client using SSL.

You will need configure the client such that it will trust the certificate from the broker either via a signing authority or by sharing the brokers public certificate with the client.

Comment: Do I need the key and trust store? If I need it for now just for a proof of concept, is there a way to just enable security via code?

Comment: I don't have that keytool.. is it a needed step? I tried changing the URL to this one in your article:  ssl://localhost:61617?transport.acceptInvalidBrokerCert=true     but it didn't help

Comment: keytool comes with Java for updating keystores, I don't believe you can use it for you c# client. On the server side you need both private key and certificate, while on the client side you need to trust that same certificate. There are many examples around.