# ActiveMQ Exception when trying to work with SSL

Tags: c#, ssl, activemq-artemis, nms

I'm trying to send secure messages over SSL with ActiveMQ, using the Apache NMS API for .NET.

In the broker.xml I tried adding "sslEnabled=true" to the default acceptor:

```
<acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?sslEnabled=true;tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300</acceptor>
```

I'm trying to set up a consumer like this:

```
IConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory("activemq:tcp://localhost:61616");
connection = (Connection)factory.CreateConnection();                       
connection.Start();
ISession session = connection.CreateSession();
IDestination destination = session.GetTopic("topic1");
consumer = session.CreateConsumer(destination);
consumer.Listener += new MessageListener(HandleMessage);
```

When the code reaches the line `connection.Start()`, I get this exception:

> Channel was inactive for too long: tcp://localhost:61616/

I have tried changing the connection url like this (ssl in the middle instead of tcp):

```
IConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory("activemq:ssl://localhost:61616");
```

And then I got this exception:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

What am I doing wrong here? How can I send and receive secured messages?

Comment: From cmd.exe >Ping localhost.  Is the machine IP returned or the loopback 127.0.0.1?  Check if the service is running cmd.exe >Netstat -a which will give list of TCP connection and ports.

Comment: "Reply from ::1: time<1ms"

Comment: Also, when not using the addition in the acceptor of "sslEnabled=true", and just trying to send regular messages, it does work

Comment: I get same results.  The localhost file has all comments (starting with #).  The localhost file is located in folder : C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc.  You probably want to use the environmental variable COMPUTERNAME and use the name instead of localhost.  You can get list of environmental variable cmd.exe >SET

Comment: it's 127.0.0.1 like expected

Comment: Is the service running using Netstat?  If the service is running and is connected to 127.0.0.1 you cannot also use 127.0.0.1.  So you must use the machine IP address or name.  Service should really use IP.Any instead of the loopback so the clients can use loopback.

Comment: The service is running. Like I said, when it works when using regualr tcp and not SSL. So what should be the change here?

Comment: See codeproject : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1000189/A-Working-TCP-Client-and-Server-With-SSL

Comment: @jdweng that's not ActiveMQ with Apache NMS

Comment: You need to get the certificate from the FACTORY.  See if this codeproject is better : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1063910/WebSocket-Server-in-Csharp

Comment: Have you tried this `var cf = new Apache.NMS.Stomp.ConnectionFactory("stomp:ssl://0.0.0.0:61613")`?

Comment: @HoangPhuocTruong I've tried IConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory("activemq:ssl://localhost:61616")

Comment: @jdweng how do i create certificates? By Factory, you refer to the ConnectionFactory in my code?

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806299/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-using-c